# How to read and modify IOS app .strings file

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, localizable.strings

I have vendor provided IOS app .IPA file which allow us to do some changes like images, icon, text/label etc. but I am unable to update one of the App front end screen label from corresponding locale .strings file.

When I open that file in Xcode or text editor , its show something like in attach image (xcode screen) and even if I replace some string in it the app start showing key name all over the app UI instead of key's value or label.
The file should be in key value format to update the labels but its not.

Any reason why this file content looks like this but not in key value format.

[xcode screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUxh9.jpg)